# Linq bridge performance

Tags: c#, linqbridge

Has anyone here used [Linq Bridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx)
If so, what is its performance like? Is it a full replacement for linq?

Answer (score 5):

I've been using LinqBridge in a real-world application for a few months, and I'm quite happy with it. I haven't run any performance tests, but the implementation of most operators is quite straightforward, so I don't think there's a significant performance difference with the official MS implementation.

Note that LinqBridge is definitely not a *full* replacement for Linq : it covers only Linq to Objects (implements the `Enumerable` methods). There's no support for expression trees, Linq to XML, Linq to DataSets, Linq to SQL...